# Calculating time between page visit and form $POST submit in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, I wanted to get the time difference between user entering a page (that contains a contact form named "sampleform") and actual submitting the form via $_POST method. So I created a test script like below, but it doesn't seem to work - it always show the time as 0. Why it doesn't work:

```
$enterTime=time();

if(!empty(($_POST['sampleform']))) 
echo 'You submitted the form after '.(time()-$enterTime).' seconds';
```

Comment: `$enterTime` will be reset on every request, so you're currently timing how long it takes to get from that line, to 3 lines later, which is negligable. You probably want to set it to a session variable (taking care not to overwrite it when the form is posted), retrieving it and comparing that to `time()`.

Comment: Good point -- so it's not possible to keep $enterTime without losing it (using something else than session variable) - I know only how to do simple things like that :

Comment: Well there are other mechanisms you could use to persist the data, but using $_SESSION is by far the simplest and is built-in when using PHP

Comment: Ok, maybe a solution would be to store this variable as the "hidden" field on the form..

Comment: Yep, that would also work quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks, now I know why it wouldn't work, it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting `$enterTime` every time you run this code, so `time()-$enterTime` will always return 0. As has been mentioned, you could keep this value in a session variable, but if you don't want to use sessions, you could also use a hidden input in your form instead e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="enterTime" value="<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Then you would write

```
if(!empty(($_POST['sampleform']))) 
    echo 'You submitted the form after '.(time()-$_POST['enterTime']).' seconds';
```